# Cloud Shell environment: Create custom image failing to SSH

Tags: dart, google-cloud-platform

Cloud Source Repository, gives you a cloudshell base on nodejs docker image.

I am trying to create a custom image for my repo, The docker image I am building downloads and installs Dart.

I follow the tutorial, created my image it builds fine `#cloudshell env build-local` but when I try to ssh into the container it fails.

[image]

How do I whatever is blocking me to access the docker instance?
I have looked at the firewall rules (maybe did it wrong).

Comment: Your VPC's firewall rules do not affect Cloud Shell. Cloud Shell is not running inside your VPC. The problem is you broke the container. Test the container on your desktop in Docker and figure what change broke the container.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks, I needed to Dockerize an SSH service
`
EXPOSE 22 \n
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
`

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to have a cloud console with Dart Support.
Dockerfile

```
FROM gcr.io/cloudshell-images/cloudshell:latest
// Download & Install dart
RUN apt-get -q update
RUN apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y -q gnupg2 curl git ca-certificates apt-transport-https openssh-client
RUN curl https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian/dart_stable.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dart_stable.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install dart
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV DART_SDK=/usr/lib/dart
ENV PATH=/usr/lib/dart/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

EXPOSE 22
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

See [Dockerize an SSH service](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/) for more information.

The above will create a cloud console which will allow you to execute dart files.
Do follow the tutorial on how to add custom image.